# Why does java's RandomAccessFile not return on linux?

Tags: java, linux, named-pipes

I'm new to java and was trying to read and write to named pipes (created in another native C++ process) using RandomAccessFile. Here's my code :-

```
String input_pipe = "/home/user/some_pipe";
try {
  System.out.println("here1");
  RandomAccessFile inp_pipe = new RandomAccessFile(input_pipe, "r");
  System.out.println("here2");
} catch (Exception exp) {
  System.out.println("Some error opening pipe :- " + exp.getMessage());
}
```

When I run this code, all I get on the output is :-

```
here1
```

And the process just doesn't return. Any tips on what I'm doing wrong or how I can debug this?

Comment: For one thing, you can't randomly access a pipe; it's not seek-able (though you might be fine unless you call `seek`). On Linux, if you open a pipe, your process will block until something else opens the other side of the pipe.

Comment: So what should I use instead? This website seems to suggest using that :- http://carminedimascio.com/2014/01/named-pipes-with-java/

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo - RandomAccessFile only means that it can be opened for reading and writing according to the given mode, has nothing to do with seeking... So the problem is only that it will block until another process opens the pipe for writing.

Comment: @mata Yes you are right. If I open it in "rw" mode, it doesn't block.

Comment: @mata As another aside, how would I know that the constructor blocks? The javadoc at { https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#RandomAccessFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String) } doesn't say anything about the constructor blocking on no data, only says that read will block on no data.

Comment: Then the docs for the constructor are incomplete. To open a pipe without blocking, you'd have to open the pipe in non-blocking mode, which I don't think `RandomAccessFile` supports.

Comment: @owagh - it blocks because that's just how pipes on linux work, the underlying `open` system call blocks until the other end of the pipe is opened (usually by a different process). it doesnt't block in `rw` mode because both ends of the pipe are opened (by the same process in this case). The example you linked to only uses RandomAccessFile because it writes and reads to the same pipe, but you can also use a FileInputStream/FileOutputStream instead.

Comment: Do either of you want to put that in an answer? I'll accept the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since none of the commenters chose to write an answer, I'll write one myself.

The problem is that opening a named pipe on linux will block until the other end of the pipe has also been opened. You can either open it in non-blocking mode or open both ends of the pipe at once.

Comment: Hi @owagh,
Could you please provide some hints, code samples about these options.
I tried FileInput/OutputStream and that also seem to be getting blocked in the constructor.
Thanks in advance.